# Is there a need to resize a UIImage when setting it to an UIImageView to conserve memory?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

When setting a `UIImage` to a `UIImageView`, I know that iOS automatically scales the image so that it fits within the ImageView. However, if I am loading a very large image file as a `UIImage`, will iOS automatically cut down the size of the `UIImage` (and therefore conserving memory) until it is just enough to fit the ImageView?Or do I have to implement the trimming of the image myself?

How do I trim the size of the `UIImage` if it is needed to do so?

Comment: I think swift will not resize the image. You need to do it. http://nshipster.com/image-resizing/

Comment: In order to trim an image you still need to load it into memory and to add the trimmed image as well. So you will not conserve any memory.

Comment: @MaxPevsner If you release the memory of the large image after trimming it then you will conserve memory.

Comment: @Swinny89, of course you will, but while trimming the image the memory will be higher than it could be without performing any operations on that image. And that unnecessary memory peak might be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's optional to set the size of the image , the memory conservation will not be there if there if you set the size or not.Image will be set into the frame size of UIImage view.
This function will do the resizing of the image.

```
func ResizeImageToRequired(image: UIImage, targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
let size = image.size

let widthRatio  = targetSize.width  / image.size.width
let heightRatio = targetSize.height / image.size.height

// Figure out what our orientation is, and use that to form the rectangle
var newSize: CGSize
if(widthRatio > heightRatio) {
    newSize = CGSizeMake(size.width * heightRatio, size.height * heightRatio)
} else {
    newSize = CGSizeMake(size.width * widthRatio,  size.height * widthRatio)
}

// This is the rect that we've calculated out and this is what is actually used below
let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)

// Actually do the resizing to the rect using the ImageContext stuff
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
image.drawInRect(rect)
let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

return newImage
}
```

here you can use the above function and set the size to required Width and Height in CGFloat.

```
 self.ResizeImageToRequired(UIImage(named: "yourImageName")!, targetSize:      CGSizeMake("width", "height"))
```